# Decomposing direct product of irreps

Tags: group-theory, representation-theory, characters

I know characters of two 2-dimentional irreps (U and V) of a group with 6 conjugate classes. The characters are: $\begin{pmatrix} 2&-1&-1&2&0&0\end{pmatrix}$ and $\begin{pmatrix} 2&1&-1&-2&0&0\end{pmatrix}$. Sizes of conjugate classes are 1,2,2,1,3,3 respectively.

I want to deduce decomposition of $U\otimes V$ into sum of irreps from this information. Is it possible? Do I need Clebsch-Gordan series for this?

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen you are right, sorry for the typo

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The character of the representation $U\otimes V$ is $(4\ -1\ 1\ -4\ 0\ 0)$.
We can calculate the following inner products
$$
\langle \chi_{U\otimes V},\chi_{U\otimes V}\rangle=\frac1{12}(16+2+2+16)=3.
$$
This implies that $U\otimes V$ is a sum of three pairwise non-isomorphic irreducible representations. One of the components is thus 2-dimensional and the other two are 1-dimensional.

$$
\langle \chi_{U\otimes V},\chi_{U}\rangle=\frac1{12}(8+2-2-8)=0,
$$
and
$$
\langle \chi_{U\otimes V},\chi_{V}\rangle=\frac1{12}(8-2-2+8)=1,
$$
so we can deduce that the 2-dimensional component is isomorphic to $V$. No further information can be deduced from the given data. But there are relatively few isomorphism types of groups of order 12, so it is not a stretch to think that we might be able to positively identify it. Leaving that to somebody else :-)

Comment: Thanks, I was hoping to miraculously obtain decomposition without having to calculate other characters, but on the second thought getting all the characters in my original problem was relatively easy.

Comment: There are actually two groups with these conjugacy class sizes.  The dihedral group of order 12, which also happens to be $S_3 \times S_2$, and the so called dicyclic group of order 12.  This is definitely a character of $S_3 \times S_2$, in which case it is relatively easy to complete the rest of the decomposition. It may also be a character for the dicyclic group though, I'm not sure.